# ffplay keep video/audio sync when using select filter

Tags: select, audio, filter, ffmpeg, synchronization

I'm trying to play/skip some clips of a video using ffplay. My first approach to skip say frames 100 to 400 was:

```
ffplay -vf "select='lte(n\,100)+gte(n\,400)'" -i INPUT
```

this skips the desired frames, however it also freezes the video during the skipped frames. I tried to fix this by modifying the video presentation time stamp (PTS) with the setpts option:

```
ffplay -vf "select='lte(n\,100)+gte(n\,400)',setpts='PREV_OUTPTS'" -i INPUT
```

this seems to work (stills freeze a bit, guess is because of buffering), but now the audio is out of sync. I've tried applying a select filter and modifying the PTS on the audio as well

```
ffplay -vf "select='lte(n\,100)+gte(n\,400)',setpts='PREV_OUTPTS'" -af "aselect='lte(n\,100)+gte(n\,400)',asetpts='PREV_OUTPTS'" -i INPUT
```

this skips some audio frames, but still out of sync. I've tried with the aresample=async=10000 option with similar results. Moving some/all of the filters to the output (placing them after the -i INPUT) doesn't work either.

Does someone know how to skip parts of a video using ffplay? Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Audio frame numbers **!=** video frame numbers. AAC audio generated by FFmpeg's encoder is 1024 samples per frame, so a 48kHz stream has 48000/1024 = 46.875 audio frames per second. Other codecs may have different rates.

Use `t` instead of `n`, and generate a continuous series of timestamps.

```
ffplay
-vf "select='lte(t\,4)+gte(t\,16)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB"
-af "aselect='lte(t\,4)+gte(t\,16)',asetpts=N/SR/TB"
-i INPUT
```

I assume a video frame rate of 25 fps. Modify accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! You are an absolute genius. Is this frame precise or does it select the nearest key frame?

Comment: Frame precise. Filters work on fully decoded frames, so there are no keyframes.

Comment: @gyan can you give us how to modify if say 30 or 60fps? or some docs to read up on it?

Comment: In select,  think of  `4`  as `starting_frame_num/fps` and `16` as `ending_frame_num/fps`. Substitute accordingly.